# Not able to scroll page up and down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In web  page there are two sections(sections are not frame it is implemented using "div") one is a menu and other is a details page. Both sections have scrolls bar vertically but i am not able to scroll both sections up and down. please help me to sort out this issue

i have used given my code below but its dint work:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
```

(or)

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
```

Please help me

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

This is working alright for me in each case.

Please tell me if it is helpful or not